# Calculate zoom level to fit an image into a panel

Tags: c#, .net, 2d, system.drawing

How could I calculate the zoom level (graphics scale) to fit any image to any panel?

The image size and the picture size could be any size.

The method signature I need is the following:

```
  public float CalculateZoomToFit(Image image, Panel targetPanel)
  {
     // I need to calculate the zoom level to make the picture fit into the panel
     return ???
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ratio of width over height for both the panel and the image is the key for the answer.

```
var panel_ratio = targetPanel.Width / targetPanel.Height;
var image_ratio = image.Width / image.Height;

return panel_ratio > image_ratio
     ? targetPanel.Height / image.Height
     : targetPanel.Width / image.Width
     ;
```

Add checks for divide-by-zero errors, if you want.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of terinary boolean operators in general, but this is remarkably elegant.  Well done.

Comment: Thanks, I used your answer; (btw var should be replaced with decimal or float)

Answer (score 0):

In general, it'll be the width or height (depending on what you want to fit) of the container divided by the width or height of the object you're putting in it.  This will give you the adjustment you need to make to the image for it to fit.